# Can I do intent in a fragment like this?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

can I do an intent in a fragment like this? the program crashes once I press the button.

```
public class PagesFragment extends Fragment {



@Override
 public void onStart() {
  super.onStart();



  Button sendBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.sendEmail);
  sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
         Intent i= new Intent("claimrewardemail");
         startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes you can do that - include your logcat output which will have info about why you are crashing.

Comment: +1 @Booger include your logcat also check for your layout xml file whether the defined id is identical with the one you defined here

Comment: http://i62.tinypic.com/29hf8h.png, this is the error, I tried the code, but still have problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do an intent in a fragment like this.

*Example*

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false); //(1)

            Button sendBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sendEmail);   //(2)

          sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          //(3)
          public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i= new Intent(getActivity(),WhereUWant2Navigate.class); //(4)
            startActivity(i);
          }
      });
    return view;
    }
```

*Explanation*

1. You get the view. *Line (1)*.
2. Then you get the button from that view using `view.findViewById`. *Line
   (2)*.
3. Then you can use `setOnClickListener` on the button. *Line (3)*.
4. Your `action` of `Intent` is wrong *Line (4)*

`WhereUWant2Navigate.class` is 2nd `activity` which you want to open from that `Fragment`.

**UPDATE:**

For the problem - http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=29hf8h&s=8#.U74yDZSSzH8

This problem arises when there is `android:onClick="onClick"` set in your layout xml.
You have already defined your listener in the class so need to define in the layout xml.
So remove it from layout xml.

Comment: Hi, I tried, but seems it has error when I click, it crashes.

Comment: Updated the answer. You have two listeners for the same onClick event. You need only one. Either remove `android:onClick="onClick"` from xml OR remove setOnClickListener from code and keep just the onClick method.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your button isn't created in `onStart`. Please move the code in there to `onViewCreated`

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated() {
    Button sendBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.sendEmail);
    sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent i= new Intent("claimrewardemail");
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Need logcat. Your sure youre

```
Intent i= new Intent("claimrewardemail");
```

gives you a "real" thing?

Like others mantioned, you should be fine with code like this:

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void openMyActivity(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LanguageGuideActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And then use this function on a button (or wherever you want).

Like:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="150sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Calculate"
    android:id="@+id/btn_calculate"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="openMyActivity" />
```